# Comentários de múltiplas linhas em Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-basic-6, comentários

Tem como eu colocar comentários de múltiplas-linhas em Visual Basic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Infelizmente, não há um modo de criar um comentário de múltiplas linhas na linguagem BASIC, mas tem alguns "truques" que podemos fazer:

**Truque 1: #If**

Você pode tentar criando blocos `#If` com expressões inexistentes, isso o compilador irá ignorar o bloco. Exemplo:

```
#If Comentario Then
     Isso é
     um comentário
     de várias linhas
#End If
```

**Truque 2: REM**

Mesma coisa do caractere `'`, você pode definir como no exemplo:

```
REM linha 1
REM linha 2
REM linha 3
```

**Truque 3: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (Somente Visual Studio 2008+)**

Esse é simples, basta digitar o código, selecionar o que deseja comentar e apertar <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> (somente no Visual Studio 2008+)

Answer (score 1):

Modo mais rápido e fácil (tem os botões no painel superior):

- *Selecione as linhas* -> **Para comentar**: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
- *Selecione as linhas* -> **Para remover comentário**:  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>

Comment: Esse atalho é para **Visual Studio Code** ou para **Visual Basic**??

Comment: Para **ambos**, pois tentem a usar o mesmo padrão. Confirmei olhando na documentação.