# Qual a função de #if false no C#?

Tags: c#

Estou trabalhando em um projeto e vi blocos de código com isso com `#if false`:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Qual a diferença pra isso (comentado vs `#if false`) ?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

O [#if](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if) é uma [diretiva de pré-processamento](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/cc564864.aspx) que te permite passar parâmetros para o compilador.

Quando você faz

```
#if false
 ...
#endif
```

O compilador entende que **não** é para compilar/interpretar o bloco do `#if`.

Um uso mais comum dessa diretiva é:

```
#if DEBUG
    Console.WriteLine("Olá mundo!");
#endif
```

Que executará o bloco somente se o projeto estiver em modo de `DEBUG`.

**A diretiva** `#if false` **não funciona como um comentário.**

Dentro do comentário você não precisa respeitar a sintaxe do C#, por exemplo, 
o `#if false` faz com que o compilador exclua tudo desse bloco da compilação mas não ignora ele completamente igual a um comentário, portanto o compilador ainda olhará o texto que está dentro do bloco.

Por exemplo, o código abaixo gerará um erro:

```
#if false
 #foo
#endif
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Certo, e qual a real diferença entre o #if false e você comentar o bloco de código ?

Comment: @ThiagoLoureiro muita. Coisas de pré-compilação podem ser resolvidas através de inclusão de headers, ou através de comandos jogados para o pré-compilador

Comment: Em VB.NET, `#if` [funciona como um comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/66789/24529).

Answer (score 6):

No seu caso nenhuma, o resultado será o mesmo. Porém muitas ferramentas de refatoração/análise de código pode marcar comentários no código como um code smells (o que na verdade é).

Pensando na compilação do seu código, a diretiva (#IF) é interpretada antes mesmo de começar a análise léxica e será análisado se aquele código será utilizado no processo de Build (preciso de fontes que confirme essa afirmação). No seu caso já que a condição é sempre false, ele não fará parte do build.

O comentário será ignorado na hora que a análise léxica fazer a leitura tentando criar tokens conhecidos.

Comment: Compreendi, parece simples mas no detalhe 'e interessante entender, tks+1

Answer (score 6):

### Compilação Condicional

O `#IF` é um comando de pré-compilação. Com ele você pode modificar seu código conforme parâmetros (constantes) que você definir ou usar constantes pré-definidas como o `DEBUG` ou `TRACE`.

Se você abrir a janela de opções de build do projeto vai ver uma janela parecida com essa:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como pode ver, na caixa de símbolos condicionais eu cadastrei uma constante chamada `MINHA_CONSTANTE`. Dessa forma eu posso criar um código do tipo:

```
#IF MINHA_CONSTANTE
     ... código que vai compilar apenas quando essa constante estiver definida
#ENDIF
```

E dessa forma quando você quiser, pode ir na aba do build e retirar essa constante ou adicionar outras e seu código vai compilar de acordo com essa lógica que você definiu.

Por esse motivo que um `#IF false` não tem muito sentido e ele faz o mesmo trabalho que comentar o código, já que aquele trecho não será compilado.